# Ошибка при запуске task(а) gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Я скачал node js вот этой версии:

Завантажити для Windows (x64)
12.13.0 LTS.

Установил gulp, вот так:

npm i gulp@3.9.1 -g

npm init

npm install gulp --save-dev

Потом создал gulp как в видео

Вот мой проект: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u1G-cQ1GcE_ZHHV0sNreevEkUNXwNnJr

Но я всё равно получил эту ошибку при запуске
[image]

Прошу помогите!

Answer (score 0):

В новых версиях gulp таски пишутся по другому

```
const { src, dest, parallel } = require('gulp')
const pug = require('gulp-pug')

function html() {
  return src(
      'templates/*.pug'
    )
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(dest('build/html'))
}

function myTask() {
    console.log('myTask')
    // ...
}

exports.myTask = myTask
exports.html = html
exports.default = parallel(myTask, html)
```

Comment: у меня версия gulp 3.9.1,Поэтому всё написано правильно

Answer (score 0):

В вашем файле Package.json указана загруженная версия gulp 4.0.2